# In Knowledge Graph triples / Information extraction How do we represent a negative imperative sentence in triple format?

Tags: nlp, information-extraction, nlp-question-answering, knowledge-graph

In Knowledge Graph triples / Information extraction How do re represent a negative imperative sentence in triple format?

Eg. sentence :"Do not install the Gadget X in a damp or dusty place" ,
1)How would the triple should be represented in Knowledge Graph?

2)If I want to ask a question " Should I install Gadget X in a damp or dusty place" ? and My Gold Answer is "No", how this kind of relationship ("No/Not") should be captured in triple format?